# Can I use one sample wilcoxon signed rank test for time series data where I need to check if all of the data points are below a theoretical value?

Tags: time-series, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have time-series data and I want to check if the data I collected is below a certain theoretical value. Is the one-sample Wilcoxon signed-rank test the best way for my objective?

Some background information on what I am trying to do. I have designed an alternative system and I am now checking if my designed system's performance is within the standards set (in this case, the standard is the maximum allowed).

For the specifics, my time series data is the aggregate speed/rate of the tasks being processed (i.e. each data point is in seconds). The data is seasonal if that matters. Based on the graphical representation the data is below the threshold, what I am trying to do is to find a statistical test, to prove that my time series data is below the theoretical limit "most" of the time.

Comment: The *data* are either below the threshold or they are not. You can answer that question for certain with no need for inference.

Comment: It may be useful to explain more about the situation, perhaps you mean to consider a question about something other than the data (like whether the population mean is below the threshold, or whether some proportion of the population of values is below the threshold, etc)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Glen_b, Hi, I edited the question to add some details on what I am trying to do.

Comment: Are the tasks independent of each other?

Comment: @jbowman, I think so, the tasks come are queued from many sources and just fed to the machine

Comment: Well, for example, if it's software, it may be that tasks run simultaneously but if enough of them are running at once they may compete for machine resources.  Is the data the processing time of each task?  If so, it's not really time series data, it's just a collection of observations of processing times.